# Podio Contact API Untegration

Tags: podio

I am trying to integrate Contacts API with one of our application. One of my client has created API ID and APP token key. I am using NuGet Package of  Podio.

I am trying to use GetContactTotals. But I am not able to fetch no. of records. It is throwing an error. I have used AuthenticateWithApp method. Actually our goal is we have to fetch the contacts and sync with our application. When I use AuthenticateWithPassword method it fetches Contacts, which is more than in that particular app.

Could you please help with any example with which I can achieve this?

Comment: GetContactTotals need user authentication. It returns contact that the user shares with. Do you want to get all contact in a specific app?

Answer (score 0):

GetContactTotal method requires user authentication. Apps don't have access to user's contacts.

Also, some of contacts methods are deprecated (e.g.: https://developers.podio.com/doc/contacts/get-space-contact-totals-67508), so you might want to redesign how to store all contact information and use apps and particularly "Contacts App".

More details on how to organize contacts are here: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201019938-Using-a-Contacts-app-Importing-Contacts